# weird smoothing issues

Tags: modeling

So new to Blender but semi-versed in MAX so sorry if my wordings a little off. I have a weird shading issue, I have this smoothing issue visible in the screen capture, I've tried using the smooth function in the edit>shading menu, I've also tried flipping normal and neither change anything. My modifiers are, subdivision surface and mirror modifiers. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.[image: the problem is most visible around the eyes but also at the chin and cheecks]

Comment: So what areas are we talking about? Eyes, mouth, cheeks...? How does the topology look like? Tris, quads, ngons? Oh, so many questions...

Answer (score 2):

There might be few point that you want to know:

1. You don't get enough subdivision times, usually not going further then 2~3 times. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1~0</kbd> within object mode can set sub-modifier.
2. Your *mask* (I guest?) topologies are not suitable for subdivide, it has some holes with special case that blender nowadays can not resolve well. See the reference: [Subdivide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/subdivide.html)
3. The *smooth shading* AFAICT use **Gouraud Shading** in the view-port fast rendering. There is fake normal in the calculating pipeline, you might confused that by another common shading: **Phong Shading**.

   [image: Gouraud Phong Shading]
   No need to worried about it since in Cycles render, it use try tracing with other method to calculate the color and normal.