# What's the shading algorithm behind Smooth Shading?

Tags: shaders, lighting

When I flip between flat and smooth shading, I see that the vertex normals flip between n vertices for n meeting faces and single (averaged) normal.  Once the vertex normals are deduced, how're objects with *Smooth Shading* rendered?  I'm interested in the shading algorithm/interpolation model ([Phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading), [Gouraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading), etc.) than the illumination model (like [Blinn-Phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model), etc.) used.  When smooth shading, are lighting calculations done per-vertex or per-fragment?

I'm a graphics programmer (OpenGL) who recently started learning Blender.  I'd like to understand how Blender works under the hood for better understanding.

I searched in the manual but couldn't find anything regarding this, understandably.  The [Blender 3D Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Normals_and_Shading) says *Phong* while [an answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140069/53932) says *Gouraud*.

When flat shading, the usual technique is to just shade the entire tri or quad with one lighting calculation performed with the face normal.  I hope this holds true with Blender too.

Comment: Hey there! In case you didn't know, Blender is also open-source, so you can take a look at its source code to see how it does smooth shading.

Comment: Here is the source code for Blender: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) Yes, reading the code is an option, while having someone (with context) explain it to you is a lot better.  However, I'd do this if we don't get any answers.  Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want a pointer to the code in question. What engine are you asking for workbench, Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: @Robert The viewport renderer; not sure of its name though. Is that the one called _workbench_?

Comment: @legends2k yes that is the workbench engine.

Comment: It's not that easy to read the Blender's source code if you have never worked with it. However, it is likely that it uses Gouraud for the smooth shading because in the parts of the code where it is mentioned there are several operations that include vertices and their interpolation. Maybe someone more expert could clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As phong uses interpolated vertex normals this is the method used checking the docs of the source code.

source: https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/01a2bd03695f217616acc2581fe8746f5cd226d7/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py#L672

```
def shade_smooth(self):
        """
        Render and display faces smooth, using interpolated vertex normals,
        removing the "sharp_face" attribute
        """
        _name_convention_attribute_remove(self.attributes, "sharp_face")
```

Answer (score 3):

"Phong" and "Gouraud" are not always used consistently between sources.  If we consider Phong shading to be a shading algorithm where the interpolation of vertex normal is used to light fragments, and Gouraud shading to be a shading algorithm where the interpolation of vertex lighting is used to light fragments, then Workbench uses Phong shading.

We can see this by looking at the specular highlight of a smooth shaded object in Workbench:

[image]

The vertices of this smooth shaded cube are all darker than the specular highlight in the middle of the face.  That highlight cannot be created by interpolation of vertex lighting.  As a comparison with Gouraud shading, you can see the demonstration of specular artifacts at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading .

As for how we get that fragment normal, it is the renormalized weighted average of vertex normals of its (triangulated) face's vertices.  The weights are the barycentric coordinates of the fragment.  If we'd like, we can see these coordinates by using a geometry/parametric node in a shader.

Comment: Agree with the inconsistent usage of the term; it's why I'd used different terms in my question: _interpolation model_ (where/how many calculations are done) vs _illumination model_ (calculations made at each unit to arrive at a colour).